# Javascript Bingo "free" space

Tags: javascript

```
function populateN() {
  var nNumbers = [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45];
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tempString = "r" + (i + 1) + "c3";
    var temp1 = nNumbers.length;
    var temp2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * temp1);
    var temp3 = nNumbers[temp2];
    document.getElementById(tempString).innerHTML = temp3;
    nNumbers[temp2] = nNumbers[0];
    nNumbers.shift();
  }
}
```

how do you overwrite the table cell “r3c3” with the string value of “FREE”

Comment: `document.getElementById("r3c3").innerHTML = "FREE"` after the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this ?

```
document.getElementById("r3c3").innerHTML = "FREE";
```